# Querying a mongo collection for objects without certain attributes using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm looking to write a find clause that will search for objects where a certain attribute exactly matches a condition or if the object doesn't have that attribute at all.

Currently I am using:

```
  Card.find( { $or: [ { "playerClass": req.params.className }, { "playerClass": {'$eq': null } } ] }, function(err, docs) {
    res.json(docs);
  });
```

But this yields no results.

I tried $equals before as well to no avail -- as a newcomer to Mongo, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`null` counts for missing, so you could use `$in`:

```
Card.find({ "playerClass" : { "$in" : [null, req.params.className] } }, callback)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! I'd vote you up too but unfortunately I'm below the reputation threshold -- I'll be back when I have enough!